# Plot specific jumps in value range of a matrix

Tags: matlab

I have a `matrix <1x1000>` which consists of different values such as 30, 50, 50, 50, NaN, 80, 80, 90, 100, 100, 100, NaN, NaN, 70, 70 etc.

Now I want to `plot` a graph where the difference between elements at least is 20 (plus/minus), therefore for instance everything that goes from 80 to 90 will be excluded.

I have no idea how to do this, the data is used for my hobby project (want to learn matlab). Therefore all help is appreciated!

Comment: Start off by using `abs(diff(matrix))>20`, what comes after will depend on what you think your plot should do.

Comment: When you say the difference between elements do you mean the difference between elements that are right next to each other, or between every pair of elements?

Comment: Between every pair.